# how to use azurerm_subscription_policy_remediation with existing policy

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I'm having trouble reading in a policy as a data block to remediate the policy.

The error is with the scope_id.   I have used a azurerm_resouce_group.id, but it says
"Policy Assignment Name: "Test-Inherit-RequiredTag-IheritedTag" was not found"
I'm trying with the subscription Id , which it then said it expected "/subscriptions/" so I added that.  Now it is "malformed or invalid."

I have also tried

scope_id = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000/providers/microsoft.authorization/policyassignments/test-inherit-requiredtag-iheritedtag"

What is expected for the scope_id ?

```
data "azurerm_policy_assignment" "policy_assignment1" {
  name     = "Test-Inherit-RequiredTag-InheritedTag"
  scope_id = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}"
}

resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_remediation" "remediation1" {
  name                 = "remediation1-inherit-tag"
  subscription_id      = var.subscription_id
  policy_assignment_id = data.azurerm_policy_assignment.policy_assignment1.id
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to use azurerm_subscription_policy_remediation with my existing policy and I was successfully executed the `terrafrom_plan` & `terraform_apply` commands.

I have referred the code from this  [official Terraform exemption document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subscription_policy_exemption) & [[official Terraform remediation document]](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.59.0/docs/resources/subscription_policy_remediation) and modified it accordingly.

The module mentioned in the question.

```hs
data "azurerm_policy_assignment" "policy_assignment1" {
  name     = "Test-Inherit-RequiredTag-InheritedTag"
  scope_id = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}"
}
```

It was not worked for me as well, so I ended up modifying the modules as per the requirement and able to produce the output you're looking for.

**My [main.tf](http://main.tf/) code:-**

```
terraform {

required_providers {

azurerm  =  {

source  =  "hashicorp/azurerm"

version  =  "=3.59.0"

}

}

}

  

provider  "azurerm" {

features {}

}

  

data  "azurerm_subscription"  "example" {}

  

data  "azurerm_policy_set_definition"  "example" {

display_name  =  "Audit machines with insecure password security settings"

}

  

resource  "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment"  "example" {

name  =  "exampleAssignment"

subscription_id  =  data.azurerm_subscription.example.id

policy_definition_id  =  data.azurerm_policy_set_definition.example.id

location  =  "westus"

  

identity {

type  =  "SystemAssigned"

}

}

  

resource  "azurerm_subscription_policy_remediation"  "example" {

name  =  "example"

subscription_id  =  data.azurerm_subscription.example.id

policy_assignment_id  =  azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment.example.id

}
```

**Output:**

While executing `terrafrom_plan`

[image]

While executing `terraform_apply`

[image]

By using the script, I was successfully performed all terraform steps and the desired output.